# Connecting Postgres ODBC to SQL Server Reporting Services/Data Tools/Report Builder

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0, report-designer

I've been using Crystal Report for my Adempiere (ERP Software which i believe use Postgres ODBC)

I want to try SSRS cause i've heard some good things about it. At this point i just want to try the SQL Server Data Tools to try and create some reports and see whether i find it easy before attempting to deploy the reports on SSRS. So i'm guessing i should focus on connecting the SQL Server Data Tools or Report Builder?

Anyway, I've tried to follow the instructions from here (http://postgresblog.blogspot.com/) to "New Linked Server". I come across Error:7303

"An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo) ->
Cannot Initialize the data source Object of OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "Adempiere".
OLB DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "Adempiere" returned message "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application" (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 7303)

I've tested the DNS Server and its successful.

At this point i'm abit lost on whether im going in the right direction. I just want to try and use SQL Server Data Tools or Report Builder to see if im comfortable creating reports on it. Before the actual deployment of SSRS.

I hope you all can help me with this problem here... Thanks alot! Sorry if all these sounds very noob... My IT manager quit and i used to rely on him to solve all these problems

Comment: Did you get step 7 fixed? For me ODBC doesn't seem to be identified...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit ago that I worked with SSRS. But if I remember correctly you just have to add a connection as described in Step 7. You do not need a linked Server to query data from an other sources. Do you get the same error while creating a new data source in SSRS?

Comment: Hey Mara, Thanks for the reply. just before i left work i actually tested on another computer and it works for linking server. Im going back into work tomorrow and try it out again and let you know. Thanks for replying!

Comment: @mara I have an issue creating as per Step 7. In SSRS I am unable to find an ODBC that works for postgres instead OLEDB...

Comment: Is the ODBC Connection (the one created on step 3) working? Maybe you need  "Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services ODBC data processing extension" http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ff519546.aspx / http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152816.aspx

Sorry I have no idea and no system to test it.